# What does the notation $\sum_{d\mid (k,n)}$ mean?

Tags: summation, notation, binomial-coefficients, divisor-counting-function

I'm trying to understand how to generate [this sequence](https://oeis.org/A047996), but I'm confused about this notation:

$$\sum_{d\mid (k,n)}$$

Does it mean the sum of all factors of both $k$ and $n$?

Comment: I would interpret this as the sum over the divisors of the gcd of $k$ and $n$.

Comment: $(k,n)$ is a shorter form of $\gcd(k,n)$ and so $\sum_{d\mid(k,n)}$ is a short form of $\sum_{d\text{ such that }d\mid\gcd(k,n)}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sum of the form $$\sum_{d \mid n}$$ is a sum where $d$ takes all the positive divisors of $n$.

The notation $(k,n)$ is often used to represent $\gcd(k,n)$, the greatest common divisor of $k$ and $n$.

So $$\sum_{d \mid (k,n)}$$ mean that the sum is taken over all the positive divisors of $(k, n)$.

Note that been a divisor of $(k,n)$ is the same as been a divisor of both $k$ and $n$.

Answer (score 2):

It means that you are summing over the divisors of $\gcd(k,n)$. In other words, you are summing over the natural common divisors of $k$ and $n$.

Comment: It seems the compulsive anonymous downvoter is lurking around again…

Comment: ... summing over the **positive** divisors of ...

Comment: @jjagmath Indeed. Thank you.